# Delayed loading of exported functions behaviour

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, dllimport

I am trying to understand how delayed loading of exported functions works (with c++ on windows).

As far as I understand you could either import some '*.h' and call a function. The compiler and even more the linker will take care of everything, as well as the windows loader (which will then correct the exact addresses according to the memory layout at the time of execution). Another option would be to load the address of an exported function at runtime, convert it to a function pointer and just run it.
So I used a simple example to allocate a char array and print the contents:

```
void writeChar(char* char_space, SSIZE_T len)
{
  memset(char_space, 0x41, len);
}

int main()
{
  // Allocate a buffer
  SSIZE_T len = 10;
  char* char_space = (char*) VirtualAlloc(NULL, len, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  // write to it
  writeChar(char_space, len);

  // print chars omitted for readability...
  return 0;
}
```

This works as I expect it to work. I just threw it into a windows console application in VS and it compiled and worked nicely.

So I tried to just load it at runtime. I copied the exact function header from `memoryapi.h` and tried to find it in the exporting DLL (`kernel32.dll`).

```
typedef LPVOID (*loadedAlloc) (LPVOID lpAddress, SIZE_T dwSize, DWORD flAllocationType, DWORD flProtect); 

void writeChar(char* char_space, SSIZE_T len)
{
  memset(char_space, 0x41, len);
}

int main()
{
  // Load the functions address (assume kernel32.dll is loaded)
  loadedAlloc Alloc = (loadedlAlloc)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "VirtualAlloc");

  // Allocate a buffer
  SSIZE_T len = 10;
  char* char_space = (char*) loadedAlloc(NULL, len, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  // write to it
  writeChar(char_space, len);

  // print chars omitted for readability...
  return 0;
}
```

This is behaving totally different. The address is effectively loaded and the call also retrieves a memory address (one that looks good). But after it is passed to the function "writeChar" the memory address (at least in the debugger) changes. This will then result in some `AccessViolation` on the next write (`memset`-call) and the program is terminated.

So how do these calls differ?

Comment: Your code does not compile. `localAlloc` being undefined, `loadedAlloc` is used as a typedef and as a function name, ... After fixing the obvious errors I can compile and run it just fine.

Comment: Your function pointer declaration is missing the calling convention. The code failing at some point is to be expected.

Comment: Dang. You are totally right. That was it.